# Certificate exceptions when running Scala SBT on Docker Alpine Linux container

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, typesafe-activator, alpine-linux

I have a Dockerfile with the following base image:

`FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim`

In the same Dockerfile, I also run: `activator compile`

When I run `$ docker build -t some_name .` on my MacBook, the SBT step works as expected.

When I run the very same command, over the very same Dockerfile, on a remote Ubuntu host (EC2 instance on AWS), I get many certificate errors like the following:

```
[info] Resolving org.webjars#strip-json-comments;1.0.2-1 ...
[error] Server access Error: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching repo.typesafe.com found url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.webjars/strip-json-comments/1.0.2-1/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching repo.scala-sbt.org found url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.webjars/strip-json-comments/1.0.2-1/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching repo1.maven.org found url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/webjars/strip-json-comments/1.0.2-1/strip-json-comments-1.0.2-1.pom
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-rjs;1.0.7 ...
[error] Server access Error: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching repo.typesafe.com found url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-rjs/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.0.7/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching repo.scala-sbt.org found url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-rjs/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.0.7/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching repo1.maven.org found url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-rjs_2.10_0.13/1.0.7/sbt-rjs-1.0.7.pom
```

It seems SBT is contacting repositories to download dependencies, and being unable to validate their SSL certificates. However, the very same process works and downloads heaps of dependencies without any problem when `docker build` runs on my MacBook. Thus, it looks like there's some difference in the environments between my MacBook and that Ubuntu host. However, Docker is expected to provide full isolation and consistent behaviour, no matter where it runs.

Does anyone have a clue about what could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I identified the problem, although I can't explain why it happens.

The EC2 Ubuntu host that displays the inconsistent behaviour with Docker has an `iptables` rule like this:

```
$ sudo iptables -L -t nat
[...]
Chain xyz (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https /* xyz */ redir ports 8443
```

The rule is in place to redirect all inbound traffic from port 443 to 8443. It is meant to redirect traffic to a Java-based application that runs on the same machine and has a self-signed SSL certificate.

When I run a Docker container on the same machine with Docker's default network settings, and I issue an HTTPS wget from within the container, Docker, or the OS, seem to redirect the outbout connection to port 8443 on the Ubuntu host, and, therefore, to the local Java-based application which, in turn, accepts the connection (most of the times) and returns invalid (self-signed) certificate details that cause the `java.security.cert.CertificateException`s I observed before.

However, the `iptables` rule should be affecting only inbound connections to the host. Can anyone explain why outbound connections from within the Docker container are being redirected to the local port?

How can these `iptables` settings be affecting Docker?

Answer (score -1):

Image `frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim` doesn’t use Alpine’s official Java package, but Oracle JDK (that is distributed only as a binary compiled against glibc) with a glibc hack to make it somehow run on musl-based system. It’s *not* supported by Alpine and I strongly discourage you from using it.

You should use `openjdk:8-alpine` image instead or just plain Alpine image and simply install openjdk8 package.
SBT works fine here.

---

If you want to try the latest version that now includes also patches from IcedTea, then use plain Alpine image and install openjdk8 from the edge branch:

```
echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories
apk update
apk add openjdk8
```

It’s generally not a good idea to mix packages from stable and edge, there may be ABI incompatibilities. Thus it’d be better to also upgrade your system to edge: replace `v3.X/main` with `edge/main` in `/etc/apk/repositories` and run `apk update && apk upgrade`.

---

Oracle JDK is only a branded (proprietary) distribution of OpenJDK (that is open-source), the code base is nearly identical. This means that almost all Java applications that runs on Oracle JDK 8 runs also on OpenJDK 8.

You can find more information in [my comment in gliderlabs/docker-alpine](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/11#issuecomment-237842562).

Comment: The exact same thing happens using `openjdk:8-alpine` as a base image. Moreover, the major issue remains: Docker is behaving inconsistently on two different environments, MacOS and Ubuntu.

Comment: Does network connectivity and DNS actually work inside your container on AWS? Can you ping e.g. repo1.maven.org?

Comment: Yes, that's the first thing I checked. If I am on the EC2 Ubuntu host, and not in the container, I can download anything with wget, including the dependencies that SBT can't.

Comment: Well, it seems this is the place where the inconsistent behaviour happens. If I run the image on my MacOS machine, I can use wget successfully. If I run the image on the Ubuntu EC2 host, I get "connection refused" for the very same wget commands. And now, this is even more inconsistent, because with wget they are not certificate errors. I checked this several times, and it's always the same behaviour. Wget works on the EC2 host directly, but not on Docker over the same host, while on my MacOS, it works fine in both cases.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with SBT or Java, you have just wrongly configured network for Docker...

Comment: What do you mean? Docker should use the standard network settings. The doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/ says _The bridge network represents the docker0 network present in all Docker installations. Unless you specify otherwise with the docker run ..., the Docker daemon connects containers to this network by default._ How could I have wrongly configured networking for Docker? Both my Docker installations are standard, Ubuntu and MacOS. No settings were customised on neither of them, but, still, Docker on Ubuntu shows inconsistent behaviour.